# Why can't I pass an argument to my function through a WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm working on a simple program that (upon an HTML "click" event) sends a file to a Node.js server, which then uploads the file to Pinata IPFS via the Pinata API.

My issue is that the Pinata API function "pinFileToIPFS()" doesn't want to accept my argument once it's been sent through socket.io (from client to server). Here is the relevant code:

Client-side:

```
  <body>
    <button onclick="emp()">BUTTON</button>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();

      function emp() {
        socket.emit("file path", '"./Transparent_Image_1.png"');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Server-side:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("file path", (msg) => {
    pinFileToIPFS(
      "d33029fc...",
      "af645fbcbfe4a...",
      msg
    );
  });
});



pinFileToIPFS = (pinataApiKey, pinataSecretApiKey, path) => {
  url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`;
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(path));

  const metadata = JSON.stringify({
    name: "img",
    keyvalues: {
      exampleKey: "exampleValue",
    },
  });
  data.append("pinataMetadata", metadata);

  //pinataOptions are optional
  const pinataOptions = JSON.stringify({
    cidVersion: 0,
    customPinPolicy: {
      regions: [
        {
          id: "FRA1",
          desiredReplicationCount: 1,
        },
        {
          id: "NYC1",
          desiredReplicationCount: 2,
        },
      ],
    },
  });
  data.append("pinataOptions", pinataOptions);

  return axios
    .post(url, data, {
      maxBodyLength: "Infinity", 
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
        pinata_api_key: pinataApiKey,
        pinata_secret_api_key: pinataSecretApiKey,
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      //handle response here
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      //handle error here
    });
};
```

I've already ruled out the possibility that my sockets aren't set up correctly; if I log "msg" to console, I get back "./Transparent_Image_1.png" as expected.

I've also ruled out the possibility that my Pinata API isn't set up correctly; if I explicitly pass "./Transparent_Image_1.png" into pinFileToIPFS(), the file gets uploaded to Pinata as expected.

I'm not getting any error messages at all, just no upload... This usually happens when you call pinFileToIPFS() without specifying a file path, or simply giving one that doesn't exist. I know "./Transparent_Image_1.png" exists (and works when passed explicitly) so I'm left to conclude that msg just isn't getting passed at all. But why? I'm still a novice, so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you putting literal double quotes in the argument string? Get rid of them. It should just be `'./Transparent_Image_1.png'`. Also, the pathname will be interpreted relative to the server's working directory, not the URL of the page.

Comment: @Barmar This worked, thanks! I was clearly confused about having to pass my file path with literal quotes smh...